# Jacoco - method code too large when using ver 0.7.6 and 0.7.5

Tags: java, tomcat, exception, jacoco

I am trying to set up to run Jacoco agent (http://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.jacoco/org.jacoco.agent/0.7.6.201602180812), and I am getting an exception as below.

```
    java.lang.instrument.IllegalClassFormatException: Error while instrumenting class ...
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:93)
    at sun.instrument.TransformerManager.transform(TransformerManager.java:188)
    at sun.instrument.InstrumentationImpl.transform(InstrumentationImpl.java:428)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass1(Native Method)
    at java.lang.ClassLoader.defineClass(ClassLoader.java:760)
    at java.security.SecureClassLoader.defineClass(SecureClassLoader.java:142)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClassInternal(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:3114)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.findClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1342)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1823)
    at org.apache.catalina.loader.WebappClassLoaderBase.loadClass(WebappClassLoaderBase.java:1703)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.Introspection.loadClass(Introspection.java:143)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationServletAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:132)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.WebAnnotationSet.loadApplicationAnnotations(WebAnnotationSet.java:65)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.applicationAnnotationsConfig(ContextConfig.java:415)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.configureStart(ContextConfig.java:892)
    at org.apache.catalina.startup.ContextConfig.lifecycleEvent(ContextConfig.java:386)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleSupport.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleSupport.java:117)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.fireLifecycleEvent(LifecycleBase.java:90)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5405)
    at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:150)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1574)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase$StartChild.call(ContainerBase.java:1564)
    at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:266)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1142)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:617)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:745)
Caused by: java.io.IOException: Error while instrumenting class org/apache/jsp/isml2jsp/cartridges/app_005fbusiness_005fmanager/default_/product/batch/AttributeValue_002d37d0cd03a157eeffaecd90c11598827569e0327d_jsp.
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrumentError(Instrumenter.java:152)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:103)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:91)
    ... 25 more
Caused by: java.lang.RuntimeException: Method code too large!
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.asm.MethodWriter.getSize(MethodWriter.java:2036)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.asm.ClassWriter.toByteArray(ClassWriter.java:827)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:84)
    at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.core.instr.Instrumenter.instrument(Instrumenter.java:101)
    ... 26 more
```

The Java Option to run the Jacoco agent is set as:

```
JAVA_OPTS=$JAVA_OPTS\ -javaagent:/myserver/tomcat/lib/jacocoagent.jar=destfile=/tmp/jacoco.exec
```

I am not using a Maven or Ant file to run it, and the option to run the agent is set directly in the Tomcat startup script. Can anyone please help?

Comment: Java has hard limit on method size, that is 64K. That means if bytecode for your method exceeds 64K, java will throw this exception. Only solution is to refactor code in smaller methods

Comment: Thanks @SangramJadhav. I realize that. The problem is I am having difficulty finding whether it's the source code of Jacoco or our code base that's causing the failure.

Comment: claerly exception occured at org.jacoco.agent.rt.internal_14f7ee5.CoverageTransformer.transform(CoverageTransformer.java:93) from the stack trace?

Comment: As a alternative you can skip the same method by setting the same in <exclude> in pom.xml or if you are using remote Instrumentation by jacoco - same can be done in  "$JAVA_OPTS -Djava.protocol.handler.pkgs=org.apache.catalina.webresources -javaagent:/opt/jacocoagent.jar=output=tcpserver,address=*,port=10001,destfile=/opt/,excludes=*<name_of_file>